# css override delete unused styles bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i want to delete unused styles in css, or override them. The standard style looks like this:

```
.datepicker table tr td span.active, .datepicker table tr td span.active:hover, .datepicker table tr td span.active.disabled, .datepicker table tr td span.active.disabled:hover {
background-color: #006dcc;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom,#08c,#04c);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(to bottom,#08c,#04c);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#08c),to(#04c));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom,#08c,#04c);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom,#08c,#04c);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#08c,#04c);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0088cc', endColorstr='#0044cc', GradientType=0);
border-color: #04c #04c #002a80;
border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1) rgba(0,0,0,.1) rgba(0,0,0,.25);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);
```

i want to make it

```
.datepicker table tr td span.active, .datepicker table tr td span.active:hover, .datepicker table tr td span.active.disabled, .datepicker table tr td span.active.disabled:hover {
background-color: #93A630;
}
```

I use for this purpose a bootsrtrap-override.css

but only the value of the `background-color` changes.
How to delete the rest unused? I don't want to delete it in the original css file!

Answer (score 2):

If by *"How to delete the rest unused?"* you mean how to **reset** the CSS so that there is no gradient etc then you'll have to reset those properties in your `bootstrap-override.css`.

There's barely a `reset` or `default` property in CSS to use consistently so you'll literally need to override the previously set CSS.

This would make your snippet look like:

```
.datepicker table tr td span.active,
.datepicker table tr td span.active:hover,
.datepicker table tr td span.active.disabled,
.datepicker table tr td span.active.disabled:hover {
    background-color: #93A630;
    /*additional resets*/
    background-image: none;
    filter: none;
    border-color: transparent;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

This would remove the styles by overwriting them in a normal way without deleting contents from the original file.

Since you're already setting the styles for `:hover` state and extra classes you're good to go - but, watch out for other selectors that might have a `:hover` or `:active` for instance that isn't in your original reset-selector!

## edit 1 (12-11-2015)

After doing some googling for `unset css property` I found pages on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/)

1. [`unset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset) - [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=unset)
2. [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) - [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=initial)
3. [`inherit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit) - [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=inherit)

As you can see the browser support for anything except `initial` is anything but good so this would be your only go **IF** you can drop support for Internet Explorer which I do think can happen within the next 2 - 3 years due to Microsoft's new browser [Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/microsoft-edge).

browserstats come from http://caniuse.com, my main source for checking browser compatibility.

Hope the links help.

*All dates are formatted dd-mm-yyyy*

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `background-image: none;` for it to actually turn the color you want

Example:

```css
p {
      background-color: #006dcc;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom,#08c,#04c);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(to bottom,#08c,#04c);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#08c),to(#04c));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom,#08c,#04c);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom,#08c,#04c);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#08c,#04c);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0088cc', endColorstr='#0044cc', GradientType=0);
    border-color: #04c #04c #002a80;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1) rgba(0,0,0,.1) rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}

p{
    background-color: #93A630;
    background-image: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Test</p>
```

If i didn't answer your question correctly please tell me so in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your css

```
background-image: none;
border: 0;
text-shadow: none;
```